# angular ng-repeat add style on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

i am using ng-repeat on a list of divs and i am manually adding items in the json that it's rendering this divs. I need to position the last div that i add in json and it's automatically rendiring on the screen, where the couse cursor is, and the rest of them remain on same position, but without giving the position in the json that is rendering it.

My approach on this was something like this

```
<div ng-repeat="contact in jsonContacts" style="left: {{lastX}}px; top: {{lastY}}px;"></div>
```

but when i do this, all the divs get this position, so i need to make a condition using $last variable to add or remove the style tag with those left and top css.

Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*See this <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGBrown/GA2wR/)</kbd> for examples of both approaches (using color as position is harder in jsfiddle)*

**Option 1: ng-style and a scope function**

ng-style will let you do this, and to keep it tidy and testable you should define a scope function such as below (ternary operators are [not currently supported](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/guide/expression) in angular expressions for stable 1.0.x versions of angular, [although 1.1.5 has added ternary support](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/6798fec4390a72b7943a49505f8a245b6016c84b)).

```
ng-style='myStyleFunction($last)'
```

In the controller, define:

```
$scope.myStyleFunction = function($last) {
  return {
    'left': $last ? $scope.lastX + 'px' : '',
    'top': $last ? $scope.lastY + 'px' : ''
  };
}
```

**Option 2: custom directives**

Or, you could think even more "angular" and define a directive:

```
dirModule.directive('positionLast', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, $element, attrs) {
            if (scope.$last) {
              // if jQuery is present use this, else adjust as appropriate
              $element.css("left", $scope.lastX + 'px');
              $element.css("top", $scope.lastY + 'px');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and then:

```
<div ng-repeat="contact in jsonContacts" position-last> ...
```

**EDIT** This works by using `scope: true` and declaring the directive on the `ng-repeat` element. As only one new scope is created for all directives on an element (assuming at least one requests a new scope) then it gets access to the [`ng-repeat` scope values](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat). For the relevant documentation see:

- [Directives: Directive Definition Object (scope / true)](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

> scope - If set to true a new scope will be created for this directive. If multiple directives on the same element request a new scope, only one new scope is created.

Comment: everytime i ask something, fom the answer i understand that Angular is more powerful and complex than i previously tought :D thank you very much, i will also try to see how that scope inside directive works to retrieve the $last from the ng-repeat :)

Answer (score 5):

Based on you html, you should try this

```
<div ng-repeat='contact in jsonContacts' ng-style='{"left":($last?lastX:null)+"px","top":($last?lastY:null)+"px"}'>{{item}}</div>
```

Here is the fiddle for confirmation http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/yFc6J/1/

Comment: I thought you [can't use conditional logic in expressions](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/guide/expression), so this won't work?

Comment: @AndyBrown It does actually, ateast in 1.5.1 See my updated fiddle.

Comment: You are right, I didn't have room in the comment to talk about versions. See my answer for info. I do assume the use of the current stable 1.0.x branch for SO questions unless the OP states otherwise.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work until you add style="position:absolute" to the repeated elements and "position:relative" to their parent div.